# Netgear GS724T - all lights are always on

Tags: switch, netgear

I have a Netgear GS724T "Smart" switch. When I power it on, all the lights come on. I have tried a factory reset, but this has not changed the behaviour of the switch.

Has this switch failed, or is this a config issue I can resolve?

Comment: Have you done anything to confirm either switch actually works? Port numbers, configs? Need far more detail in the question. It also sounds like the TP-Link is irrelevant.

Answer (score 6):

Your switch is stuffed. I believe this switch has a lifetime warranty. Give Netgear a call and get them to send you a replacement.